# How to make histogram bars to have different colors in Plotly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

I am making a histogram using plotly package in R and below is the chart.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
plot_ly(test, x = ~count, type = 'histogram',  marker = list(color = 'blue'))
```

I am wondering if there is a way to make the chart more intuitive from a color perspective (eg. different colors for each bar) as the chart below.

Here is an example I found online:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot_ly(test, x = ~ count, type = 'histogram',
        marker = list(color = viridis::viridis_pal(option = "C", direction = -1)(4)))
```

Comment: Thank you. On the histogram, the x-axis would skip numbers if I expand the number of bins. For example, I increased the number of bins from 4 to 11. However, the x-axis only displays 2, 4, 6 etc. but skipped 1, 3, 5 etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
plot_ly(test, x = ~count, color = ~count) %>%
  add_histogram()
```